# Trying to install virtualbox - unmet dependencies

Tags: virtualbox, dpkg, dependencies

So I am trying to install virtualbox 6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and it seems to be having dependency problems.

I've confirmed the sources.list file contains

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
```

and I have used `update` multiple times with nothing showing up to be updated.

Also `apt-get -f install` did not help either. Here is what I get when i run `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.0 : Depends: libqt5x11extra5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: pdf-viewer
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` doesn't return anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Odd, I have virtualbox 6 installed on ubuntu 18.04.1 and `apt policy libqt5x11extra5` returns `N: Unable to locate package libqt5x11extra5`

Comment: The line in my sources.list looks like this: `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib` I suggest adding the [arch=amd64] and trying again.

Comment: I just fixed it by adding `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe` to my sources.list file

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Consider posting your solution as an answer to help the next person.

Comment: @sean So wasn’t your problem just a [disabled Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)?

Answer (score 1):

got mine working by changing sources.list line

```
deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

to

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu and ran into this dependency problem. Only difference is I'm using xenial distrubution. So here's what fixed it. From this [forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=99485).

User scottgus1 stated the following "I'm going to guess that unless you have specifically pointed your repository for Virtualbox to official [www.virtualbox.org](http://www.virtualbox.org) Virtualbox via the command on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads, then you're pulling a fork of Virtualbox, and an old fork at that. Forks may be modified from the official version and we don't know what modifications were made. We recommend official Virtualbox for Linux."

So I literally changed the command:

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1

to:

sudo apt-get install virtualbox

Worked instantly for me.